# codeigniter Undefined index: cacheClass

Tags: php, google-api, codeigniter-3

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: cacheClass
>
> Filename: src/Google_Client.php
>
> Line Number: 109
>
> Backtrace:
>
> Error code

```
public function __construct($config = array()) {
  global $apiConfig;
  $apiConfig = (isset($apiConfig) && is_array($apiConfig)) ? $apiConfig : array(); // initialize if necessary
  $apiConfig = array_merge($apiConfig, $config);
  self::$cache = new $apiConfig['cacheClass']();
  elf::$auth = new $apiConfig['authClass']();
  self::$io = new $apiConfig['ioClass']();
}
```

Comment: please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve this isnt enough to recreate the issue.   it has nothing to do with a google api.

Comment: Simple, your $apiConfig does not have an index called 'cacheClass'. Also on the next line, not sure the Elfs are going to be helpful :)